# c# Regex to filter the ID of a youtube video

Tags: c#, regex, youtube

I am aware that there are similar questions but I haven't actually seen one that goes over every possible youtube url.
The Regex that I have already covers almost everything but 2 eventualities.

`(?<=(https?\:\/\/)?(m\.)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtube\.de|youtu\.?be|youtube-nocookie\.com)/(.*?)(/|embed|vi?=|\?vi?=|watch\?|watch\?vi?\=?|watch\?v%|a=|u/1))([A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})`

I filter for the beginning of the URL until after the .com. Then it doesn't matter what is in the link until the 11 char ID. Since there are other possible matches for [A-Za-z0-9_-]{11} except the ID, I have included every possible prefix for the ID (/|embed|vi...).
Now the 2 eventualities where the Regex doesn't work are

[https://www.youtube.com/user/IngridMichaelsonVEVO#p/a/u/1/QdK8U-VIH_o"](https://www.youtube.com/user/IngridMichaelsonVEVO#p/a/u/1/QdK8U-VIH_o%22)

and

http://youtu.be/-wtIMTCHWuI

the first because there is a 11 char string right after a / (Ingrid...)
and the second one because every other URL has more than one / before the ID.
I'm not sure how to solve this.
For the user URL I have tried (?!.*(user/(.*?)/)) to exclude everything after a user/whatever/ but that just deletes the match of the whole line, even if the ID was matched as well as the username.
I am aware that the link doesn't really have an ID since it links to a profile, the problem is that it has shown me the possibility of there being another string besides the ID that my regex filters

For the second one I have no idea how to solve it because in my eyes the 2 / are needed in every other URL.

Here's the list I'm working with

https://gist.github.com/rodrigoborgesdeoliveira/987683cfbfcc8d800192da1e73adc486

With an additional iframe for testing

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BKapPQxcR3Q" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below regex. Captured group 1 will have video id.

```regex
(?:(?:(?<=[vi])(?:=|%3D)|\/))([A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})[&?\s#%\"]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TCFNk0/1)

Comment: That's a good regex to get the whole URL but I need specifically the video ID. Thank you though

Comment: @Evil-E I have updated my answer above. Please check the demo.