# Grabbing Youtube ID From URL Works Only If Using ?variable=URL and not /URL

Tags: php, regex

I'm not sure what would cause this.. and I'm wracking my head trying to figure it out.

```
?url=youtube&switch=info&get_id=https://youtu.be/TxcmdhjmnEE
```

The above URL will properly give me back "TxcmdhjmnEE" with the below:

```
if(isset($_GET['get_id'])){$get_id = $_GET['get_id'];} else {$get_id = '';}

if(filter_var($get_id, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
     preg_match("/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'>]+)/", $get_id, $matches);
     $get_id_final = $matches[1];
} else {
     $get_id_final = $get_id;
}

echo $get_id_final;
```

But once I switch to using my clean htaccess URL, the above will no longer provide the match. It just returns the original URL string. So I'm extremely confused what would cause this.

```
youtube/info/https://youtu.be/TxcmdhjmnEE
```

Maybe it has to do with the B Flag?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9|]+)/([^/]*)/(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&switch=$2&get_id=$3 [B,QSA]
```

Comment: Please refer [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707805/c-sharp-regex-to-filter-the-id-of-a-youtube-video) also.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... it was because of the B Flag.... it removes a slash from the URL... so I have to preg_match, cause it no longer is a URL, and just remove a slash from that too.. and for good measure, have another elseif for the original preg match so the non-pretty URL works still too.

```
if(preg_match("/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'>]+)/", $get_id)) {
     preg_match("/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'>]+)/", $get_id, $matches);
     $get_id_final = $matches[1];
} elseif(preg_match("/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'>]+)/", $get_id)) {
     preg_match("/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'>]+)/", $get_id, $matches);
     $get_id_final = $matches[1];
} else {
     $get_id_final = $get_id;
}
```